# Get jaccard distance between rows without preformong one hot encoding on the column in python

Tags: python, distance

I have a table that looks like that:

```
id   feature_1  feature_2  feature_3
1       A          x          r
23      A          v          r
56      B          z          r
```

I want to create some sort of Jaccard distance between the rows (ids) in an efficent way and without converting the feature to one hot encoding cols (a lot of possibilities).

How can I get a result of sum of the similarity between rows? something like that:

```
id_1  id_2  similarity  num_of_features  distance
 1     23       2              3            2/3
 1     56       1              3            1/3
 23    56       1              3            1/3
```

My code:

```
def create_pairs(ids_list):
  pairs_list = []
  for (p1,p2) in itertools.combinations(ids_list,2):
      pair = [p1,p2]
      pairs_list.append(pair)

  return pairs_list

def get_distance(id_1, id_2, df):

    ????

    return distance


ids_list= list(df['id'].unique())
pairs_list = create_pairs(ids_list=ids_list)
pairs_df = pd.DataFrame(pairs_list,columns=['id_1','id_2'])
distance_list = []
for [id_1, id_2] in pairs_list:
  distance = get_distance(id_1=id_1, id_2=id_2,df=df)

pairs_df['distance'] = distance_list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it should be faster:

```
def get_distance(id_1, id_2, df):

    similarity_count = df.loc[id_1]==df.loc[id_2]
    similarity_count = similarity_count.sum(0)
    distance = 1-(similarity_count /len(list(df.columns)))

    return distance
```

Comment: Thank you it is faster, 1 hour.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no row-wise built in functionality for jaccard distance in scikit, but you can try out following:

```
from sklearn.metrics import jaccard_score
import pandas as pd 

data = [['a', 'x', 'r'], ['a', 'v', 'r'], ['b', 'z', 'r']] 
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['feature_1',  'feature_2',  'feature_3'])

print(df)
df_cmp = df.copy()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  for index_, row_ in df_cmp.iterrows():
    if index == index_:
      continue
    print(index, index_, jaccard_score(row,row_, average='weighted'))
  df_cmp = df_cmp.drop(index) #remove after as done already
```

Create a copy you will work with - so you remove already passed rows. Then you can calculate jaccard distances for rows. Output:

> ```
>   feature_1 feature_2 feature_3
> 0         a         x         r
> 1         a         v         r
> 2         b         z         r
> ```

And scores for lines:

> ```
> 0 1 0.6666666666666666
> 0 2 0.3333333333333333
> 1 2 0.3333333333333333
> ```

You can instead of printing write it to a dataframe and work with it later. This method however has complexity `O(n*log(n))`, maybe there will be something faster.

EDIT:

I somehow didn't notice you have pairs already created, thus just replace your question marks by:

```
distance = jaccard_score(df.iloc[id_1],df.iloc[id_2], average='weighted')
```

Comment: I get this error: IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds on the df.iloc[id_1].

Comment: just change it from iloc to loc

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works! the problem is that its going to take 3 hours on 4000 ids (7,998,000 pairs), is there any way to make it more efficent?